# How do I alias two virtual domains in postfix?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I host a postfix server for forwarding email for my domains. Recently, I purchased two domains for the same service, say `example.com` and `example.net` – I want my two domains to have identical aliases. Right now the only way I can find to do that is to explicitly list them all out.

I have `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, and in `/etc/postfix/virtual`, I have:

```
example.com                                     DOMAIN
user1@example.com                               bob@external-domain.com
user2@example.com                               sally@external-domain.com
user3@example.com                               mary@external-domain.com


example.net                                     DOMAIN
user1@example.net                               bob@external-domain.com
user2@example.net                               sally@external-domain.com
user3@example.net                               mary@external-domain.com
```

Is there any way to make the aliases for `example.com` and `example.net` *always* the same, or have `example.net` inherit them or something?

Note: I also host mail forwarding for several other domains with different aliases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup an all-to-all "forwarding" rule in your virtual addresses map as follows:

```
example.net DOMAIN
@example.net @example.com
```

The only downside to this is that `smtpd` will accept all e-mails in `@example.net` before attempting alias expansion and discovering that `nonexistent@example.com` doesn't exist and bouncing the message.  Whether that is worth avoiding the hassle of a bit of copy-paste is a choice only you can make.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `virtual_alias_maps = regexp:file` with something like:

```
/^user1@example\.(com|net)$/     bob@external.example.com
/^user2@example\.(com|net)$/     sally@external.example.com
/^user3@example\.(com|net)$/     mary@external.example.com
```